# How to Access PyQGS map Canvas from PyQT5 window

Tags: pyqt5, qgis

I am starting pyQgis, novice. not enough coding knowledge. please Dont ignore the Question for lack of code. please Guide.

I am having QgsMapCanvas displayed. On the menuBar of the mainwindow  (displaying QgsMapCanvas as widget) , on Click , A GUI (pyqt5) opens. GUI has one QLabel, one QLineEdit and one QpushButton.
How can i access mouse cordinates on action of pressing QPushButton. Thanking you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you click the button, the coordinates of the map are already gone.
You need to use the mouse click onto the map, e.g. by using the QgsMapTool.
Example Qgis 3.4 - console:

```
# coding: utf-8
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QLabel,QHBoxLayout
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool
from qgis.utils import iface

class CoordTool(QgsMapTool):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.setCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(event.pos())
        coords = "X: "+ str(point.x()) +"/ Y: "+str( point.y())
        print(coords)

        dlg =QDialog()
        label =QLabel(coords)
        layout=QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        dlg.setLayout(layout)
        dlg.exec_()

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
tool= CoordTool(canvas)
canvas.setMapTool(tool)
```